# perl return values from sub get mixed up

Tags: perl, hashtable

I'm trying to get 2 different hashes from a sub in perl. The hashes get mixed up in the output of the sub. Here is my simplified code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub sub1 {
    my (%h1, %h2);
    $h1{'1a'}++;
    $h1{'1b'}++;
    $h2{'2a'}++;
    $h2{'2b'}++;
    while ( (my $key, my $value) = each %h1 ){
        print "key: $key, value: $value\n";
    }
    print "\n";
    return (%h1, %h2);
}

my (%r1, %r2) = sub1();
while ( (my $key, my $value) = each %r1 ){
    print "key: $key, value: $value\n";
}
```

output:

```
key: 1b, value: 1
key: 1a, value: 1

key: 1b, value: 1
key: 2a, value: 1
key: 2b, value: 1
key: 1a, value: 1
```

Why is this happening? How can I correct it? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perl is merging your two hashes into one and storing them in your `%r1` variable, this will *always* happen unless you return *references* from your subroutines.

```
sub sub1 {
    my (%h1, %h2);
    $h1{'1a'}++;
    $h1{'1b'}++;
    $h2{'2a'}++;
    $h2{'2b'}++;
    while ( (my $key, my $value) = each %h1 ){
        print "key: $key, value: $value\n";
    }
    print "\n";
    return (\%h1, \%h2); # \(backslash) creates a hashref
}
```

Then you need to *store* those references in scalar variables:

```
my ($r1, $r2) = sub1(); # scalar variables with references to %h1 and %h2

# use %{ } to put $r1 in hash context
while ( (my $key, my $value) = each %{ $r1 } ){
    print "key: $key, value: $value\n";
}

# prints 
# key: 1b, value: 1
# key: 1a, value: 1

# key: 1b, value: 1
# key: 1a, value: 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably should read up on [references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

Perl subroutines can take a list of parameters and can return a list. For example, if I do this:

```
array_sub ( @a, @b );

sub array_sub {
    return print join ( ": ", @_ ) . "\n";
}
```

What you will notice is that the two arrays passed will get merged into a single list of parameters without any way to tell where one list began and another ended.

Similar thing happens with hashes:

```
array_sub ( %a, %b );

sub array_sub {
    return print join ( ": ", @_ ) . "\n";
}
```

This will merge the two hashes (and their keys) together into a single list that is passed to the subroutine.

To get around this limitation, you can use *references* which basically are scalar values that point to a memory location where your actual array or hash lives:

```
array_sub { \@a, \@b );

sub array_sub {
    my $ref_a = shift;
    my $ref_b = shift;
    my @sub_a = @{ $ref_a };
    my @sub_b = @{ $ref_b };
```

In the above, I put a backslash in front of the arrays to get the *reference* to the array. To *dereference* them (i.e. turn them back into arrays) I put `@{...}` around the reference.

You have to do something similar in your code:

```
my ($r1, $r2) = sub1();   #Returns references;
my @r1 = @{ $r1 };   #dereference
my @r2 = @{ $r2 };   #dereference
```

And in your subroutine:

```
sub sub1 {
    ...
    return \%h1, \%h2;
```